Galera syncronized but tables content looks different
I have a Galera replication between two mariadb 10.6.18 servers on ubuntu 22.04.
Checking the syncronization it seems ok.
SERVER 1
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep%';
+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                 | Value                                                                                                                                          |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_local_state_uuid        | cf6ab66c-00c8-11ef-be9b-3fb43c9d821b                                                                                                           |
| wsrep_protocol_version        | 10                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_last_committed          | 1657449                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_replicated              | 1785                                                                                                                                           |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes        | 2034769480                                                                                                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_keys               | 1812489                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes         | 14544144                                                                                                                                       |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes         | 1989710288                                                                                                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes        | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_received                | 401                                                                                                                                            |
| wsrep_received_bytes          | 1228877528                                                                                                                                     |
| wsrep_local_commits           | 1547                                                                                                                                           |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures     | 30                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_local_replays           | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_send_queue        | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_max    | 3                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_min    | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg    | 0.00479616                                                                                                                                     |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue        | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_max    | 15                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_min    | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg    | 0.331671                                                                                                                                       |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto     | 1656858                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns  | 36314914803                                                                                                                                    |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused     | 0.0132695                                                                                                                                      |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent       | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv       | 15                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_flow_control_active     | false                                                                                                                                          |
| wsrep_flow_control_requested  | false                                                                                                                                          |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance      | 13.9929                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_apply_oooe              | 0.0551139                                                                                                                                      |
| wsrep_apply_oool              | 0.00423953                                                                                                                                     |
| wsrep_apply_window            | 1.43508                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_apply_waits             | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_commit_oooe             | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_commit_oool             | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_commit_window           | 1.35135                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_local_state             | 4                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_state_comment     | Synced                                                                                                                                         |
| wsrep_cert_index_size         | 168                                                                                                                                            |
| wsrep_causal_reads            | 32                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_cert_interval           | 97382.9                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_open_transactions       | 1                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_open_connections        | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses      | 10.5.92.11:0,10.5.92.10:0                                                                                                                      |
| wsrep_cluster_weight          | 2                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_desync_count            | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_evs_delayed             |                                                                                                                                                |
| wsrep_evs_evict_list          |                                                                                                                                                |
| wsrep_evs_repl_latency        | 0.000346774/0.000442443/0.000526943/5.97116e-05/8                                                                                              |
| wsrep_evs_state               | OPERATIONAL                                                                                                                                    |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid              | 749f8b52-4aa0-11ef-a8a1-0726e9dc623a                                                                                                           |
| wsrep_gmcast_segment          | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_applier_thread_count    | 1                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_cluster_capabilities    |                                                                                                                                                |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id         | 55                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_cluster_size            | 2                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid      | cf6ab66c-00c8-11ef-be9b-3fb43c9d821b                                                                                                           |
| wsrep_cluster_status          | Primary                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_connected               | ON                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts         | 4                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_index             | 1                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_provider_capabilities   | :MULTI_MASTER:CERTIFICATION:PARALLEL_APPLYING:TRX_REPLAY:ISOLATION:PAUSE:CAUSAL_READS:INCREMENTAL_WRITESET:UNORDERED:PREORDERED:STREAMING:NBO: |
| wsrep_provider_name           | Galera                                                                                                                                         |
| wsrep_provider_vendor         | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_provider_version        | 4.9(rcece3ba2)                                                                                                                                 |
| wsrep_ready                   | ON                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_rollbacker_thread_count | 1                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_thread_count            | 2                                                                                                                                              |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
69 rows in set (0.001 sec)

SERVER 2
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep%';
+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                 | Value                                                                                                                                          |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_local_state_uuid        | cf6ab66c-00c8-11ef-be9b-3fb43c9d821b                                                                                                           |
| wsrep_protocol_version        | 10                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_last_committed          | 1657428                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_replicated              | 2732                                                                                                                                           |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes        | 1231603824                                                                                                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_keys               | 262367                                                                                                                                         |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes         | 2164520                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes         | 2459094                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes        | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_received                | 19296                                                                                                                                          |
| wsrep_received_bytes          | 2058235981                                                                                                                                     |
| wsrep_local_commits           | 2658                                                                                                                                           |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures     | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_replays           | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_send_queue        | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_max    | 1                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_min    | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg    | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue        | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_max    | 26                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_min    | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg    | 0.304934                                                                                                                                       |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto     | 1656858                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns  | 36316535548                                                                                                                                    |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused     | 0.000453081                                                                                                                                    |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent       | 15                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv       | 15                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_flow_control_active     | false                                                                                                                                          |
| wsrep_flow_control_requested  | false                                                                                                                                          |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance      | 27.6423                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_apply_oooe              | 0.00157692                                                                                                                                     |
| wsrep_apply_oool              | 0.00013914                                                                                                                                     |
| wsrep_apply_window            | 1.00162                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_apply_waits             | 1                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_commit_oooe             | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_commit_oool             | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_commit_window           | 1.00065                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_local_state             | 4                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_state_comment     | Synced                                                                                                                                         |
| wsrep_cert_index_size         | 109                                                                                                                                            |
| wsrep_causal_reads            | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_cert_interval           | 8558.19                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_open_transactions       | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_open_connections        | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses      | 10.5.92.11:0,10.5.92.10:0                                                                                                                      |
| wsrep_cluster_weight          | 2                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_desync_count            | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_evs_delayed             |                                                                                                                                                |
| wsrep_evs_evict_list          |                                                                                                                                                |
| wsrep_evs_repl_latency        | 0.000393626/0.000393626/0.000393626/0/1                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_evs_state               | OPERATIONAL                                                                                                                                    |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid              | 6bae9900-4aa0-11ef-b9c8-43083f1cfd9b                                                                                                           |
| wsrep_gmcast_segment          | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_applier_thread_count    | 1                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_cluster_capabilities    |                                                                                                                                                |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id         | 55                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_cluster_size            | 2                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid      | cf6ab66c-00c8-11ef-be9b-3fb43c9d821b                                                                                                           |
| wsrep_cluster_status          | Primary                                                                                                                                        |
| wsrep_connected               | ON                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts         | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_local_index             | 0                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_provider_capabilities   | :MULTI_MASTER:CERTIFICATION:PARALLEL_APPLYING:TRX_REPLAY:ISOLATION:PAUSE:CAUSAL_READS:INCREMENTAL_WRITESET:UNORDERED:PREORDERED:STREAMING:NBO: |
| wsrep_provider_name           | Galera                                                                                                                                         |
| wsrep_provider_vendor         | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_provider_version        | 4.9(rcece3ba2)                                                                                                                                 |
| wsrep_ready                   | ON                                                                                                                                             |
| wsrep_rollbacker_thread_count | 1                                                                                                                                              |
| wsrep_thread_count            | 2                                                                                                                                              |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
69 rows in set (0.001 sec)

However I found a database with mismatching content:
SERVER 1
 select count(*) from system.maillog;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   353256 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

SERVER 2
select count(*) from system.maillog;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

How is it possibile? Why the wsrep_local_state_comment variable is "Synced"?
How can I force SERVER 2 to sync from SERVER 1?

Finally I discovered that MYISAM tables are not syncronized. I had to switch to InnoDB.
